# Problems with hex

Tags: c

I get some homework, but i stack in it. Maybe you can help me. Task below.

> Read the keyboard integer in the decimal system and establishment of a new system of numbers.
>
> Output in the console number written in the new notation.

I made for 2 to 10 systems only and i can't make from 10 to 36. I tried to make in second loop something like this:

```
if ( result > 9 ) {
    printf("%c", 55+number);
} else {
    printf("%d", result);
}
```

my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int number, base;
    int i, result;
    
    scanf("%d %d", &number, &base);
    
    if ( number < base ) {
        printf("%d\n", number);
    } else {
        for ( i = base; i <= number / base; i *= base );
        for ( int j = i; j >= base; j /= base ) {
            result = number / j;
            printf("%d", result);
            number = number % j;
        }
        printf("%d\n", number%base);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I see a semicolon after the first for loop. That's probably an error.

Comment: (Don't declare loop variables at the start of the function. The compiler would have warned you, then).

Comment: @Nikolai Ruhe - semicoloms it's ok. Program working perfect, but only with 2 to 10 system of numbers. So here no mistakes.

Comment: @Nikolai Ruhe I'm using c=99, so it's ok to declare it there.

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe I think he's determining a value and putting it in `i` (variable badly named) and using it to initialise `j`. The semicolon is desired, but can be mistaken for a mistake. I would suggest to put the semicolon in a seperate line and to *+*+add comments telling the reader what you are doing+*+*

Comment: @SvenS Of course you're right. Thanks for clarification.

Comment: @Eric Posolsky Welcome to SO.  Even though a solution was posted, consider rolling back the deletion of code as the various answers are not clear without that code.  Maybe add a "[edit]" note to the end explaining your selection/thoughts.

Comment: @chux - it's take to much space at my opinion. In answer below, it's all code from include to the end. Why need to duplicated?

Comment: @Eric Posolsky  Your call - and that's fine by me.  I find seeing the original problem and final answer useful when referring to older posts for answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`else` condition needs some changes:
1. value to digit conversion needs to apply to the inner loop *and* to the final `printf("%d\n", number % base)`.  Instead of adding in both places, simply make your loop run to `j > 0`, rather than `j >= base` and only use the last `printf()` for `\n`.
2. Rather than using a magic number `55` use `result - 10 + 'A'`.  It easier to understand and does not depend on ASCII - (does depend on A, B, C ... being consecutive).
3. The rest is OK.

[edit]
@nos pointed out problem with `if()` condition.
So remove `if ( number < base ) { ... else {` and change `for (i = base;` to `for (i = 1;` making an even more simple solution.

```
  // } else {
    for (i = 1; i <= number / base; i *= base)
      ;
    int j;
    // for (j = i; j >= base; j /= base) {
    for (j = i; j > 0; j /= base) {
      result = number / j;
#if 1
      if (result > 9) {
        // printf("%c", 55 + result);
        printf("%c", result - 10 + 'A');
      } else {
        printf("%d", result);
      }
#else
      printf("%d", result);
#endif      
      number = number % j;
    }
    printf("\n");
  // }
```

Comment: Thank you so much! almost a day I killed for this task.

Comment: Note that the if condition before this else, the `if ( number < base ) {` should be removed. It's only correct if base is <= 10. e.g we need the number 10  to be printed as 'A' for base 16

Answer (score 1):

```
int number, base;
scanf("%d %d", &number, &base);

int divisor = base;
while (divisor <= number)
    divisor *= base;

while (divisor != 1) {
    divisor /= base;
    int digit = number / divisor;
    number -= digit * divisor;
    printf("%c", digit <= 9 ? digit + '0' : digit + 'A' - 10);
}
printf("\n");
return 0;
```

Caveat: Undefined behavior for numbers greater than ~200000000.

Comment: if i enter 13 - number and 16 - base, i get N from your program, so something going wrong.
Also i need to use only for loop. Thanks for reply.

Comment: @EricPosolsky Correct, I forgot the offset of 10 for letters. Edited mistake.

Comment: @EricPosolsky Now it's very close to what you did (a little more readable in my opinion).

Comment: Looks good, thank you, but we can't use while, only for loop. But I see difference now.

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track and are very close to the answer.  Your program is printing the resulting digits in two places.

I suggest making a single function to output the digits and using it in both places:

```
void print_digit(int number) {
  // your code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add characters and integers, so try something more like:

```
'A' + // some int value
```

Comment: I don't see any difference, 65 - it's A in ascii table, and it's working good, i guess problem is deeper. result is not what i expect, if it's hex system.

Answer (score 0):

On the other hand, should one like a solution that does not under/overflow, handles all INT_MIN to INT_MAX, no UB, only enter INT_MIN <= number <= INT_MAX, 2 <= base <= 36,   *and* you don't mind recursion.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void print_digit(int x, int base) {
  int quot, rem;
  quot = x/base;
  if (quot) {
    print_digit(quot, base);
  }
  rem = abs(x%base);
  if (rem > 9) {
    printf("%c", rem - 10 + 'A');
  } else {
    printf("%d", rem);
  }
}

int main() {
  int number, base;
  scanf("%d %d", &number, &base);
  if (number < 0) {
    printf("-");
  }
  print_digit(number, base);
  printf("\n");
  return 0;
}
```